# Programmer for ESP32-C3-MINI-1

Tags: arduino, esp32, programmer

I would like to know if it is possible to use the dev kit with the esp32-c3-mini-1 for flashing/programming the module.

If not, are there any recommendations for programmers to use? I am very size constrained so would like to avoid designing a pcb with a usb connection on it. I have found this: https://www.analoglamb.com/product/esp32-esp82-programmer-ch340c-breakout/
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15096

This programmer is great, I am just looking for more options with sites that I know more of (digikey, mouser, sparkfun, etc). Also any guidance on what the cts and dtr connections are from the sparkfun model would be appreciated too. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need TX, RX, RTS, DTR and GND from an external programmer. Many of these USB to serial modules don't provide a DTR pin, look carefully. Do not use 5 V versions.

This schematic is extracted from the [ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1 Schematic](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/SCH_ESP32-C3-DEVKITM-1_V1_20200915A.pdf). If you add these 4 components to your board, you can program it with such an external tool.
The first programmer you mentioned, already contains this circuit. Just use the pin marked IO0 on GPIO9 and EN on CHIP_PU here.

[image: ESP32-C3-Prog-Intf]

At the transition from low to high at the CHIP_PU signal the ESP32 samples the level of signal GPIO9. This defines the boot context.

I often use a 6TSSOP IC containing 2 NPN with 10 kohm base resistors like PUMH4,115 from Nexperia, if board space is limited.

For the enable line (CHIP_PU) I use a pullup resistor of 47-68 kohm and 10 uF to GND. This gives the USB stack on the PC side enough time for the signal toggle.

You should protect RX and TX. At least 220 ohm in series is a good idea, diode clamping even better.

Comment: sorry, did you read the question to the end?

Comment: So would the second programmer also function similarly? Where the cts and dtr would be the gpio9 and enable connections?

Comment: No, the second programmer will not work, it has no RTS signal output.

Comment: Another programmer I was looking at is the ESP-Prog. Looking at the datasheet, the program interface has the correct outputs as well. It also has a JTAG interface. Correct me if I am wring, but I would not need to use the JTAG interface to program the esp chip? Also, could I just use female to male jumper wires / breadboard instead of the gray flat cables to connect it to the esp on a pcb?

Comment: First No, second Yes.